# Does Flash support the <div> tag?

Tags: html, flash

Does Flash support the `<div>` tag? I want to convert a table tag to a div tag to display within  Flash.

Comment: you wanna display SWF in a div or a div in a TextField inside SWF?

Comment: div in a TextField inside SWF

Comment: Html page contains the <div> i want to display within flash..

Answer (score 4):

Using *htmltext* .. no  it is **not** supported.

The following tags are supported

```
Anchor tag (<a>)
Bold tag (<b>)
Break tag (<br>)
Font tag (<font>)
Image tag (<img>)
Italic tag (<i>)
List item tag (<li>)
Paragraph tag (<p>)
Text format tag (<textformat>)
Underline tag (<u>)
```

[Adobe 3.0 Language Reference](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean are you getting HTML formatted tables that need to be converted in flash? Is there any specific reason you cannot use data grids to show this table ?

Comment: You may need a HTMLParser Class to handle all of this http://www.buzzware.com.au/_blog/Coffee_into_Code/post/Pure_Actionscript_HTML_Parser_(with_thanks_to_John_Resig)/

Comment: you don't have to use `TextField::htmlText`. see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The [FTL framework](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/) is capable of [handling divs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/DivElement.html).